# Problem in embedding

Tags: lo.logic, coq, linear-temporal-logic

I want to embed  PPTL(a kind of logic) in Coq. Because of its complex
semantics, I just embed its systax.

```
  Inductive formula :Set:= 
  | For : formula -> formula -> formula 
  | Fneg: formula -> formula  
  | Fnext: formula -> formula  
  | prj : list formula -> formula->formula.
```

And then I define some axioms for it.
But I have a problem when proving this, I don't know why.

```
Axiom t2 :forall(p q:formula),('|-('x p '&&  'x q) )<->('|-('x(p '&& q))).
Theorem tt2 :forall(p q r:formula),('|-('x p '&&  'x q) ; r)->('|-('x(p '&& q)) ; r).
intros.
rewrite t2 in H.

Error: Found no subterm matching "'|-'x ?63 '&& 'x ?
```

This is part of the code.

```
Require Import Setoid.
Variables (state : Set).
CoInductive stream : Set :=
cons_str : state -> stream -> stream.
Inductive formula :Set:=
|ftrue:formula
|ffalse:formula
| For : formula -> formula -> formula
| Fneg: formula -> formula
| Fnext: formula -> formula
| prj : list formula -> formula->formula.

Definition derivable : formula ->stream-> Prop.
Admitted.

Definition model_p (f :formula) := forall pi : stream, derivable f pi .
Notation "'|- f" := (model_p f) (at level 100, no associativity) .

Notation "p '|| q" := (For p q) (at level 76, right associativity) .
Notation "! p" := (Fneg p) (at level 71, right associativity) .
Notation "f 'prj g" := (prj f g) (at level 77, right associativity).
Notation "'x g" := (Fnext g) (at level 73, right associativity).

(************************derived  formulas  ********************)

Definition and(p q: formula) : formula :=!(!p '|| !q).
Notation "p '&& q" :=(and p q) (at level 74, left associativity).

Definition imp(p q: formula) : formula :=!p '|| q.
Notation "p '==> q" := (imp p q) (at level 79, no associativity) .

Definition iff (A B:formula) :formula:= ( (A '==>  B) '&& (B '==> A)) .
Notation "p <'==> q" := (iff p q) (at level 79, no associativity) .

Definition empty := ! 'x ftrue .

Definition chop(p:formula)(q:formula):= (cons p (cons q nil)) 'prj (empty).
Notation "p ; q" := (chop p q) (at level 75, right associativity).

Axiom t2 :forall(p q:formula),('|-('x p '&&  'x q) )<->('|-('x(p '&& q))).
Theorem tt2 :forall(p q r:formula),('|-('x p '&&  'x q) ; r)->('|-('x(p '&& q)) ; r).
intros.
rewrite t2 in H.
```

Comment: What is the question? Also, please check the formatting of the post.

Comment: The problem is why the rewirte is worong.

Comment: The problem is that you need  to put some effort into writing a proper question. Edit the question above, rather than just answer in a comment. If you spent 5 more minutes on your posts, you might increase the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: `rewrite` works from left to right. `rewrite <- t2` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't rewrite with `t2` is because it doesn't have the shape as `H`. You can see this more clearly with notations turned off.

You're trying to rewrite

```
model_p (chop (and (Fnext p) (Fnext q)) r)
```

using

```
model_p (and (Fnext p) (Fnext q)) <-> model_p (Fnext (and p q)).
```

`chop` doesn't appear in the equivalence.